# Farsi or Persian file name reading under www

Tags: php, persian, farsi

I have written a php code to read file names from a directory named test under www and print the file name on a web browser. I have some files where the file names are in farsi. But the code is printing ??? on web browser instead of farsi character. I am using 64 bit window 7 pc and wamp as a server. Can anyone please tell me the where I am making mistakes in the below code? Do I also need to change anything in apache or php configuration files or any other files?

Comment: [Good reading](http://kunststube.net/encoding/)

Answer (score 0):

You can convert file name to utf-8 with iconv

http://php.net/manual/en/book.iconv.php

If you don't know which encoding your filename will come, firstly you need to learn its encoding.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.iconv-get-encoding.php

```
   $encoding = iconv_get_encoding($filename);
```